# popup window for "successfully added" in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I'm developing one project in asp.net MVC. Now I want to make popup windows for "successfully added" new values (by Form) in ViewModel. I should use JSON , AJAX and jquery technology to do this,but after 1 day tries without success , I hope to recieve help from you.

The form that i want to recieved popup "success message" is called "Measurements".

So that's the source code in viewmodel "measurements"

```
  @model ePatient.Web.Models.MeasurementModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"});
});
</script>
<h2>Create a New Account</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to create a new account. 
</p>
<p>
    Passwords are required to be a minimum of @ViewBag.PasswordLength characters in length.
</p>
<link href="../../../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            @* Measure *@
              <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasureList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Measure, Model.MeasureList))
            </div>
            @* MeasureVal *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
            </div>
            @* InsulinType *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InsulinTypeList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InsulinType, Model.InsulinTypeList, "--изберете типа на последно приетия инсулин--", null)
            </div>
            @* Insulin_amount *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
            </div>
            @* Weight *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Weight)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Weight)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Weight)
            </div>
            @* Height *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Height)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Height)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Height)
            </div>
            @* Min_pressure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MinPressure)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MinPressure)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MinPressure)
            </div>
            @* Max_pressure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
            </div>
            @* Hypoglycemia *@
                <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HypoglycemiaList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Hypoglycemia, Model.HypoglycemiaList)
            </div>
            @* Measure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestValue)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TestValue)
            @* Comment *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comment)
            </div>
                 @* Comment *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Created)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Created, new { @class = "date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Created)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $form.attr('/system/measurement/index'),
           data: $form.serialize(),
           error: HandleUnespectedError,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {

               if (response.Success)
                   alert("Success" + response.Message);
               else
                   alert("Error: " + response.Message);
           }
       });
</script>
    </div>
}
```

So that's the source code in controller "MeasurementsController :

```
    #region

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ePatient.Web.Models;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using ePatient.Web.Models;
using ePatient.Web.Utils;

#endregion

namespace ePatient.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Patient")]
    public class MeasurementController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Doctor80Entities db = new Doctor80Entities();

        public class JsonResponseModel{
   public bool Success {get;set;}

   public string Message {get;set;}
}

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var model = new MeasurementModels
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,

                MeasureList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "сутрин на гладно", Text = "сутрин на гладно"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "преди инжектиране на инсулин", Text = "преди инжектиране на инсулин"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "преди хранене", Text = "преди хранене"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "1-2 часа след хранене", Text = "1-2 часа след хранене"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "вечер преди сън", Text = "вечер преди сън"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "около 02:00-04:00 ч. през нощта", Text = "около 02:00-04:00 ч. през нощта"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "тест при неразположение(гадене,повръщане,коремна болка)", Text = "тест при неразположение(гадене,повръщане,коремна болка)"},
                        },
                HypoglycemiaList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "НЕ", Text = "НЕ",Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ДА", Text = "ДА"},

                        },
                InsulinTypeList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "БЪРЗОДЕЙСТВАЩ ИНСУЛИН ", Text = "БЪРЗОДЕЙСТВАЩ ИНСУЛИН "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ИНТЕРМЕДИЕРЕН ИНСУЛИН ", Text = "ИНТЕРМЕДИЕРЕН ИНСУЛИН "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛНО ПРИГОТВЕНИ ИНСУЛИНОВИ СМЕСИ ", Text = "ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛНО ПРИГОТВЕНИ ИНСУЛИНОВИ СМЕСИ "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ИНСУЛИН С МНОГО ГОЛЯМА ПРОДЪЛЖИТЕЛНОСТ НА ДЕЙСТВИЕ ", Text = "ИНСУЛИН С МНОГО ГОЛЯМА ПРОДЪЛЖИТЕЛНОСТ НА ДЕЙСТВИЕ "},
                        },
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MeasurementModels model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var doctor = db.tblPatients.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
                var currentUser = db.tblPatients.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserName == User.Identity.Name);


                if (doctor != null && currentUser != null && doctor.DoctorID != null)
                {

                    db.tblMeasurements.Add(new tblMeasurement
                    {
                        Comment = model.Comment,
                        Created = model.Created,
                        DoctorID = doctor.DoctorID,
                        Height = model.Height,
                        Hypoglycemia = model.Hypoglycemia,
                        InsulinType = model.InsulinType,
                        Insulin_amount = model.InsulinAmount,
                        Max_pressure = model.MaxPressure,
                        Measure = model.Measure,
                        MeasureVal = model.MeasureVal,
                        Min_pressure = model.MinPressure,
                        PatientID = currentUser.ID,
                        Test_value = model.TestValue,
                        Weight = model.Weight,
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();


                    return Json(new JsonResponseModel { Success = true, Message = "Your form has been sent"});

                }
            }
            else {
                model = new MeasurementModels
                {
                    MeasureList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "сутрин на гладно", Text = "сутрин на гладно"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "преди инжектиране на инсулин", Text = "преди инжектиране на инсулин"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "преди хранене", Text = "преди хранене"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "1-2 часа след хранене", Text = "1-2 часа след хранене"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "вечер преди сън", Text = "вечер преди сън"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "около 02:00-04:00 ч. през нощта", Text = "около 02:00-04:00 ч. през нощта"},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "тест при неразположение(гадене,повръщане,коремна болка)", Text = "тест при неразположение(гадене,повръщане,коремна болка)"},
                        },
                    HypoglycemiaList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "НЕ", Text = "НЕ",Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ДА", Text = "ДА"},

                        },
                    InsulinTypeList = new[]
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "БЪРЗОДЕЙСТВАЩ ИНСУЛИН ", Text = "БЪРЗОДЕЙСТВАЩ ИНСУЛИН "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ИНТЕРМЕДИЕРЕН ИНСУЛИН ", Text = "ИНТЕРМЕДИЕРЕН ИНСУЛИН "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛНО ПРИГОТВЕНИ ИНСУЛИНОВИ СМЕСИ ", Text = "ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛНО ПРИГОТВЕНИ ИНСУЛИНОВИ СМЕСИ "},
                            new SelectListItem {Value = "ИНСУЛИН С МНОГО ГОЛЯМА ПРОДЪЛЖИТЕЛНОСТ НА ДЕЙСТВИЕ ", Text = "ИНСУЛИН С МНОГО ГОЛЯМА ПРОДЪЛЖИТЕЛНОСТ НА ДЕЙСТВИЕ "},
                        },
                };
            }

            return View(model);
        }



        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

and that the code in the view:

```
@model ePatient.Web.Models.MeasurementModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"});
});
</script>
<h2>Create a New Account</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to create a new account. 
</p>
<p>
    Passwords are required to be a minimum of @ViewBag.PasswordLength characters in length.
</p>
<link href="../../../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            @* Measure *@
              <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasureList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Measure, Model.MeasureList))
            </div>
            @* MeasureVal *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MeasureVal)
            </div>
            @* InsulinType *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InsulinTypeList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InsulinType, Model.InsulinTypeList, "--изберете типа на последно приетия инсулин--", null)
            </div>
            @* Insulin_amount *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InsulinAmount)
            </div>
            @* Weight *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Weight)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Weight)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Weight)
            </div>
            @* Height *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Height)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Height)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Height)
            </div>
            @* Min_pressure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MinPressure)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MinPressure)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MinPressure)
            </div>
            @* Max_pressure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaxPressure)
            </div>
            @* Hypoglycemia *@
                <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HypoglycemiaList)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Hypoglycemia, Model.HypoglycemiaList)
            </div>
            @* Measure *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestValue)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TestValue)
            @* Comment *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comment)
            </div>
                 @* Comment *@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Created)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Created, new { @class = "date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Created)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $form.attr('/system/measurement/index'),
           data: $form.serialize(),
           error: HandleUnespectedError,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {

               if (response.Success)
                   alert("Success" + response.Message);
               else
                   alert("Error: " + response.Message);
           }
       });
</script>
    </div>
}
```

My problem is exastly how to get the JSON value success=true and transform it in alert popup(successfully added) ,which to redirect to some action by clicking "OK".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet?
return Json(new JsonResponseModel { Success = true, Message = "Your form has been sent"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Yes,now i tried it again and it returns me a page with a string  "{"Success":true,"Message":"Your form has been sent"}" .Perhaps the problem is in javasript in the view ,but i ca'nt still resolve it.